# UITableView cell gives wrong information

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data

I load a tableview with data from core data.
It gets loaded with text.
Each cell has a uiimageview on it. WHen the table calls `cellForRow:` it either sets the image to hidden, or not hidden, (depending on what core data says it should be.)

Code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString * identifier = @"identifier";

self.cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

HuntingRifleGuns *handguns = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *brandModel = [[handguns.brand stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:handguns.model];

self.cell.mainLabel.text = brandModel;

self.cell.nicknameLabel.text = handguns.nickname;
//Right below me, is where is set the imageView to hidden, or not hidden. 
self.cell.alert.hidden = handguns.showBadge.boolValue;

self.cell.alert.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tvicon.png"];

return self.cell;
}
```

My problem is: if i have 1 cell on the table view, it works perfect, but if i have more that 1 cell on the table, it acts up.

I want to check to see if the cell's image is hidden or not when it gets deleted:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {        

    if (!self.cell.alert.isHidden) {


        NSLog(@"showing");

    }
 else{

NSLog(@"Not showing");
}
     .........
```

But when it tests, it doesnt always do the correct thing. It just prints out either `showing` or `not showing` randomly. And i know if it should be showing or not, because it shows the image right on the cell.  What could be the reason for this?
Just a side note, the user can set the image to be hidden or not hidden in different views, but the tableview ALWAYS shows the correct data, meaning it shows the image being visible or hidden correctly, just when i test it, it doesnt always work.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a `@property` called `cell`. That won't work.

You should just use a `UITableViewCell` variable or one with your custom cell:

```
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeue...];
```

Also, your handling of strings is not very memory efficient. Use `stringWithFormat` instead:

```
cell.mainLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
       handguns.brands, handguns.model];
```

Also, to check if a view is hidden to inform your application logic is very bad practice. Rather your should have a robust data model and query the data model instead. In your case, you should query the appropriate `handguns` object if it has an image or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's odd that you're assigning the dequeued cell to a property on `self`. This will almost certainly never be what you think it is as cells are requested from `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in a non-deterministic way. You should assign the dequeued cell to a variable with local scope. Use the parameters of `-tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` to retrieve a cell to work on. For example:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([[[cell textLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"foo"]) {
      NSLog(@"showing");
    } else{
      NSLog(@"Not showing");
    }
  }
}
```

Also, when debugging an issue like this, it's often useful to reduce the problem to the simplest possible thing that still causes the problem. What happens if, instead of using a custom cell or whatever you've got going on there, you use a simple `UITableViewCell` with it's default appearance. And instead of hiding or showing an image view you've added to the cell, you just change its default text to either "foo" or "bar" or something like that? If you're still having the problem, you're code will be much simpler and easy to explain here. If you stop having the problem, you can add your custom stuff back one piece at a time until you find the modification that breaks things.